# Variable is not changed if I update it in closure

Tags: javascript, svelte

```
<script>
    let count = {value:0};
    const increase = (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        data = {...data,value: data.value+1};
    }
    const increment = ()=>increase(count);
</script>

<button on:click={increment}>
    Clicked {count.value}
    {count.value === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

I simplified my problem to this code. I have a closure function that accepts an object and tries to update it. At first, I used the 'count' variable as a number but I thought it will not pass the reference so I changed it to an object. But either ways, the count is not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code

```js
data = {...data,value: data.value+1};
```

With this line you are re-assigning a new object to *data*, removing the reference to the *data* object you passed in before. So in this case 'count' doesn't change. (You can see this because in successive clicks you keep getting `value: 0` in the logs.

If you change this to

```js
data.value += 1;
```

You will be modifying the object you passed in because here you  *do keep* the reference intact.  With this code, successive clicks will show that *count* has changed.

The markup however will not update because how Svelte works, it will only update if it sees an assignment on the variable, otherwise it has no way (or at least not a performant way) to detect changes to objects. So you have to have *somewhere* `count = ...` for Svelte to know that count has updated.

You can try this by adding

```html
<button on:click={() => count = count}>Refresh</button>
```

You will see that when clicking this button it will update the UI.

A solution might be to rewrite increment to

```js
const increment = () => {
  increase(count);
  count = count;
}
```

Or alternatively, rewrite `increase` to return the data object and reassign directly

```js
const increment = () => count = increase(count);
```

*edit for your comment on an answer*

Notice that you can also define an inline function:

```html
<button on:click={() => count1 = increase(count1)}>
 Clicked {count.value} {count1.value === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
<button on:click={() => count2 = increase(count2)}>
 Clicked {count.value} {count2.value === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
<button on:click={() => count3 = increase(count3)}>
 Clicked {count.value} {count3.value === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just re-assigning the data variable, but to change the count state you need to assign the latest object to the count variable.

```html
<script>
    let count = { value: 0 };
    
    const increment = () => {
      count = { ...count, value: count.value + 1 }
    }
</script>

<button on:click={increment}>
    Clicked {count.value}
    {count.value === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

Comment: This is not what I want to talk about. If I update the object directly in the function, it will work. What I want is update the object in the clojure function

Comment: In my problem, I have about 5 variables with the same behavior. Let's say: count1, count2,count3,count4,count5. with the clojure I can create 5 functions very easy like this incrementCount1=increase(count1). But this way of code don't make svelte change the variable

Comment: In that case, you need to store the result of the increase function in another variable and point that value to the count object. The Svelte tutorial docs mentioned that we need to re-assign both objects and arrays because references store them. [Tutorial link](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects)